Looking for equal maximums in a range
I have a list of scores and need to find the maximum value; i.e. the winner(s) but also identify any duplicates of that max value. In other words, a top score wins and on occasions there may be equal top scores; e.g.



Column A
Column B
Column C




Ali
22



Bert
24
Winner


Craig
20



Dave
18



Eric
24
Winner



I need the two values of 24 to be identified and then stored along with 'Winner' in other cells - the winner(s) enclosure
Thanks for any help, happy to use VBA if it's easier.
I've tried Max & Large functions which shows the maximum value & I can identify if there's a draw with: =IF(COUNTIF(G8:G11,G12)>1,"Draw","No Draw") but I need these two blended somehow into one.

How would you want the result to look like? Also your formula references column G, while your sample data is column A:C. Would this be helpful: =Text join(", ",,Rept(A1:A5,B1:B5=Max(B1:B5)))

I would use a combination of Max, If, Countifs, & Filter to get your expected results. Just remap the formulas to fit your needs.
First, I would find the winning score using max, then check if that row is equal to the max. If it is, label it "Winner", otherwise "".
Next, a countifs against the max score to see how many winners. If you want it to say Draw somewhere you can have the text check if the value is greater than 1 and if so "Draw", otherwise "Winner". Everything else should be fine. =If( COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,MAX($B$2:$B$6))>1, "Draw", "No Draw")
Finally, a filter to filter the table out to show the winners, you can hide their scores using a choosecols.
=IF(B2=MAX($B$2:$B$6),"Winner","")
=MAX($B$2:$B$6)
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,F2)
=FILTER($A$2:$B$6,$C$2:$C$6="Winner")

